# how to use google task (tasklist.tasks.get) in appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks-api

how to use google task (tasklist.tasks.get) in appscript?
https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/get

**i want use "tasklist.tasks.get" to find out tasks title form task.parent(ID)**.

i know need to write in 2 obj , but i don't know how to put in.
thankful for someone who can help

```
tasklist id = taskGroup.items[i].id
task id = taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent
```

```js
var taskGroup = Tasks.Tasklists.list();//Group
  for (var i = 0; i < taskGroup.items.length; i++){ 

    var taskGroup_Items = Tasks.Tasks.list(taskGroup.items[i].id)
    //try{ //如果沒try 當取TTaskList.items.length 裡面為空, so will error
     for (var j = 0; j < taskGroup_Items.items.length; j++){

      listItemAr.push([
        taskGroup.items[i].id,
        taskGroup.items[i].title,
        taskGroup_Items.items[j].id,
        taskGroup_Items.items[j].title,
        taskGroup_Items.items[j].due,
        taskGroup_Items.items[j].notes,
        taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent,
        Tasks.Tasks.get(taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent).title //<-------here
        ])
      //Logger.log(taskGroup.items[i].id + taskGroup.items[i].title + taskGroup_Items.items[j].id + taskGroup_Items.items[j].title + taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent + taskGroup_Items.items[j].due)

      
     } 
    //}catch(err){Logger.log(err)} 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Tasks.Tasks.get(taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent).title
```

#### To:

```
taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent ? Tasks.Tasks.get(taskGroup.items[i].id, taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent).title : ""
```

- In this case, `Tasks.Tasks.get(taskGroup.items[i].id, taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent).title` can be also used. But, even when `taskGroup_Items.items[j].parent` is undefined, no value from `Tasks.Tasks.get` is returned. By this, the process cost becomes hign. So, I proposed this modification.

#### Reference:

- [Method: tasks.get](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest/v1/tasks/get)

Comment: take my keen, > w <,  thx bro.

Comment: just put it togather, i starting doubt my IQ.... dann it..

Comment: @Diarox Carbon Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply and this current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it? When my answer was not useful, I have to apologize and modify my answer.

Comment: @JamesReed68 Thank you for replying. I could understand that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. Thank you, too.